# Generate an array of numbers without duplicate in Solidity

Tags: algorithm, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am building a Lottery Smart Contract in which user can buy a Ticket that have 5 generated numbers from 1 to 25 without duplicates numbers.

Everything works just fine, except that 30% of the time, Metamask says "transaction runs out of gas", because of this function.

The function below generate an array of 5 numbers between 1 and 25 :

```
  /// @dev Generate 5 numbers ( 1 <= x >= 25) without duplicate numbers
  /// @param _lotteryCount used for the random generator number function
  /// @return uint256[5] return an array of 5 generated uint

  function generateRandomTicketNumbers(uint256 _lotteryCount) internal view returns (uint8[5] memory) {
    uint8[5] memory numbers;
    uint256 generatedNumber;

    // Execute 5 times (to generate 5 numbers)
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      //   Check duplicate
      bool readyToAdd = false;
      uint256 maxRetry = 5;
      uint256 retry = 0;

      // Generate a new number while it is a duplicate, up to 5 times (to prevent errors and infinite loops)
      while (!readyToAdd && retry <= maxRetry) {
        generatedNumber = (uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block.timestamp, i, retry, _lotteryCount))) % 25).add(1);
        bool isDuplicate = false;

        // Look in all already generated numbers array if the new generated number is already there.
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
          if (numbers[j] == generatedNumber) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        readyToAdd = !isDuplicate;
        retry++;
      }
      // Throw if we hit maximum retry : generated a duplicate 5 times in a row.
      require(retry < maxRetry, 'Error generating random ticket numbers. Max retry.');
      numbers[i] = uint8(generatedNumber);
    }

    return numbers;
  }
```

I'm not sure to understand how Metamask estimates the gas of a transaction but I guess it runs locally the transaction, see how much gas it used, and use this amount for the real transaction.

If this is correct, that could explain why it fails 30% of the time. Sometime, this function needs to retry multiple times to generate a number in the "while" loop, and sometime, the "while" loop is only executed once.

I could force the function to runs every "for" and "while" loop the maximum number of time, but I believe there is a better solution than wasting gas.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Fisher-Yates shuffle can do the task with exactly 5 calls to the random number generator.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

First use chainlink as a source of randomness https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/ , follow the best practices sections https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/ , then when you get the random number you can do as they recommend in the docs

```
function expand(
    uint256 randomValue, 
    uint256 n
) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i)));
    }
    return expandedValues;
}
```